# filepath check in R both absolute and relative

Tags: r, path, relative-path, filepath, absolute-path

I have no idea how to do this.
i have a list of filepath in a column. Now i want to check if at all the filepath is absolute path or not based on both windows or Linux system.

Ex-

```
somefunction("C:\eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-win32\eclipse")
ANS: absolutepath or T
```

Comment: There is a "isAbsolutePath" function in the R.utils package.

Answer (score 7):

The package `R.utils` has a `isAbsolutePath` and `getAbsolutePath` function.

Comment: Well i am not getting anything here..is shows > ?getAbsolutePath
No documentation for ‘getAbsolutePath’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??getAbsolutePath’
> ?isAbsolutePath
No documentation for ‘isAbsolutePath’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??isAbsolutePath’

Comment: Did you install `R.utils` and then load it using `library(R.utils)`?

Comment: sorry i thought it is the default utils folder u r talking about. and is the isAbsolutePath works for both windows and Linux based path Names?

Comment: You're welcome to confirm this, as I don't have machines of all breeds at my disposal, but I believe that is the intent.

Comment: I'll keep you posted. give me some time.

Comment: I find it interesting that `isAbsolutePath("/tmp")` gives `TRUE` on Windows, but it really looks and behaves like a relative path!